# Deleting entities non-destructively in Symfony2

Tags: orm, symfony, doctrine-orm

Is there a good, clean and simple way to delete entities non-destructively in Symfony 2? I'd like to give my administrators a chance to undelete items, while sacrificing as little of the automation provided by the framework as possible.

If there is no built-in solution or third party bundle to help me, what would be the best way to do this? Adding a `deleted` property to entities would require lots of added logic to keep them from cluttering the controllers created by `doctrine:generate:crud`, so maybe they should be stored in a separate table in serialized form?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What you want is Soft Delete. There is a [Doctrine extension](https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/softdeleteable.md) for that and a [bundle](https://github.com/stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle) to integrate it with Symfony.