# Symfony2 set default query criteria

Tags: doctrine-orm, conditional-statements, default, symfony-2.8

There is an Institution entity, and institutions can be deleted. But after deletion the data is not deleted in database, a column "deleted", which has a default value of NULL, is changed to the date and time of deletion.

The project has already progressed and institutions are called in many places. The problem is that not all calls of institutions are queried by the deleted value.

To not manually add an additional where clause, I have been searching for a way to add a default condition to all institution repository queries to return only institutions with a "deleted" value of NULL. But nothing really helped.

Comment: What you are looking for is 'soft-delete` you should checkout [StofDoctrineExtensions](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle/index.html) This will apply a listener to your Entities that will only return non-deleted entries, but will still allow for DQL queries and overriding.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deleting entities non-destructively in Symfony2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10372447/deleting-entities-non-destructively-in-symfony2)